# Toad for Oracle 10.5.1.3 - How to find DataType info like in Schema Browser

Tags: oracle, browser, types, schema, toad

When using Toad for Oracle the wonderful schema browser provides a lot of information. One piece of that info that I would like to have available via a query is the Data Type information for a given table.

[image]

That extra bit of info listed in the Data Type column (1 Byte), provided in the Schema Browser is what I am looking for. When using the table ALL_TAB_COLS it provides a lot of that same info but not that additional info about the Data Type.

[image]

Is there any way to have a Select statement return that same information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DATA_LENGTH field in ALL_TAB_COLUMNS provides the the length of the column (in your case 1), while CHAR_USED flag differentiates between CHAR (C) and BYTE (B).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking right past it for over a week. :) I appreciate your help! It's funny how you can sometimes put blinders on for the answers that are right in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the column `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.CHAR_USED`

From the manual at:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277

> *B indicates that the column uses BYTE length semantics. C indicates that the column uses CHAR length semantics*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    DATA_PRECISION,
    DATA_SCALE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
Where TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';
```

If that doesn't work your table may be in capital letters so try this.

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    DATA_PRECISION,
    DATA_SCALE
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
Where TABLE_NAME = upper('table_name');
```

I wanted to add some information because of title. This is the first thing that comes up when you search for `toad check what kind of data type something is`.

Simply put the cursor on a function, table, or other object in the editor window and press the F4 key, and detail about the object appears.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/toad-for-oracle/9780134131900/ch03lev1sec3.html